# NodeJS/Express + HTTPS: How to deploy key & certificate to AWS EC2 node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, https

I am very new to Node.js & Express.js which I use to write a web API service.
To enable HTTPS the service is using the following code:

```
const server = https
  .createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/myservice.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/myservice.crt')
  })
 .listen(serverConfig.server.port, () => logger.info(`MyService is up and running`));
```

As it is easy to see, this code assumes that the `.key` and `.crt` files are available locally in the service application location.
If I want to deploy the service to a single AWS EC2 host (for simplicity reasons) these files would have to be there, which does not seem to be a secure solution.

I was thinking about using AWS IAM for securing the secrets.
The issue is that it's not possible to "deploy"/make the secrets available from IAM to an EC2 node directly.
I'd have to use IAM's API to get the secrets, but then the question is how do I make the AWS credentials available on EC2.

**Question:** Is there a recommended secure way to deploy secrets (including certificates and keys) to AWS EC2 node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to keep secrets on EC2 instances. You may use [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) to keep the secret keys and [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to manage your SSL certificates.

You could setup a [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)(ELB) in front of your EC2 instance and have your SSL certificates applied on the ELB. Here is a [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#create-https-lb-console).  It is good practice to terminate SSL at ELB level to take some load off the server on your EC2 instance.

Comment: If I apply SSL on ELB level in front of the EC2 instance, I can get rid of the HTTPS setup code in my service, correct? I also assume that there no [significant] cost changes if I configure my ELB to not grow above single instance  (my project is not even in early alpha, so I don't need it to autoscale at all).

Comment: Correct. Well there is a small cost involved. See the ELB pricing. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/classicloadbalancer/pricing

Comment: If you are concerned about cost, you can further reduce it by migrating your application to serverless. (Lambda & API Gateway). Have a look at this. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Were you able to successfully integrate your express js with ELB to use HTTPS?

Comment: @Manoj would it be okay if you can provide the solution on how to enable this?